# Notification on Document expired in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I want to create an app in which I store the documents of users, and I want to add a feature so that when the document of the user is expired, a notification will be sent to the user's email that the document is expired. I have no idea how to do it. The expiration date is set manually by the user.

The technology I am using is Nodejs and MongoDB.

I am expecting a solution to this query.

Comment: How are you expiring the documents? If it means removing them via TTL index then the workflow probably starts with change streams using [pre-images](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/#change-streams-with-document-pre--and-post-images) of the removed documents. If you're expiring the documents some other way, then you'll probably add this notification feature to that workflow

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the document and just notify the user of the expiration date, you can put a field for the expiration date in your document and use a lib like node-cron to periodically check if the document has expired.

Something like that:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const MyModel = require('./path/to/your/model');

const checkExpiredDocuments = async () => {
  try {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    await MyModel.updateMany(
      { expirationTime: { $lt: currentDate }, expired: false }, // Filter documents with expiration time earlier than the current date and that haven't been marked as expired
      { expired: true } // Set the "expired" field to true to mark the documents as expired
    );
     // notifyUser();
  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
};

// Schedule the execution of the function to check for expired documents every hour (adjust as needed)
cron.schedule('0 * * * *', checkExpiredDocuments);
```